# Is there anyway to make to write a crash handler for haxeflixel that can create logs and use a interface to a advanced error report?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, haxelib

## How to build a haxeflixel Crash Handler?

As it says in the Title I was wondering if there is any way to let haxeflixel catch a error and then pass it over to a Crash Handler of some kind?

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check and use [crashdumper library](https://github.com/larsiusprime/crashdumper/) or [code related to it](https://github.com/larsiusprime/crashdumper/blob/master/crashdumper/hooks/openfl/HookOpenFL.hx#L100) (require some settings in project file)

Comment: Thank's for the Help! I've looked into the crashdumper libary for haxe and i'm going to try build a c++ program and using the program to intercept a crash and open up a window to explain what has happened.